# The camera's view is grey/grayed and I can't see anything out of the camera's sight?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

[image]

So everything out of the camera's sight is invisible and it's there's this grey/gray (I don't know how it's spelled) thing highlighting what can be seen. What's going on and how do I fix this? I need to use assets that are out of my view. :(

Comment: I made a few typos I think. I'm tired, sorry. Point is, I can't see anything outside of the grey and I don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: Try pressing Alt-B https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are in 'clipping' mode. Simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and you should be good.